# Incorrect Request Type in Backend Deployment on Render.com - MERN App

Tags: reactjs, express, rest, mern

I have deployed my MERN app on Render.com, and I'm encountering an issue with the backend deployment. When a user tries to log in or sign up, the backend deployment returns /api/user/login OPTIONS instead of the expected /api/user/login POST. However, on my local server, I receive the correct response.

Here is an excerpt from the logs:

---

```
==> Starting service with 'npm start'
backend@1.0.0 start /opt/render/project/src/backend
node server.js
Connected to database & listening on port 4000
Your service is live 
/ GET
/api/workouts GET
/api/user/signup OPTIONS
/api/user/login OPTIONS
```

On my local server, the logs look like this:

---

```
Connected to database & listening on port 4000
/ GET
/api/workouts GET
/api/user/signup POST
/api/user/login POST
```

I have already added the CORS middleware in my server.js
file, but the issue persists.

Could someone please help me with this problem?